# No query results error using artisan with object instantiated in service provider

Tags: laravel

I have created a service provider which provides a class App\Path. This is loaded up through Eloquent using $request->getPathInfo()

```
    $this->app->singleton(Path::class, function($app)
    {
        $request = $app->make(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class);
        $path = Path::with(['template', 'parts'])->findOrFail($request->getPathInfo());
        return $path;
    });
```

The app works fine and as expected. However when I want to use Artisan I get the following error:

```
In Builder.php line 369:
No query results for model [App\Path] /
```

This prevents me from clearing caches, creating models etc. It seems that Laravel runs register() when running any artisan command and when this done, the request path is "/" which doesn't exist in the DB. Is there a better way to populate the Path object? The only way to solve this seems to add a dummy record for "/".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the app is running from console and adjust its logic, for example:

```php
$this->app->singleton(Path::class, function($app)
    {
        if ($app->runningInConsole()) {
          return null;
        }
        $request = $app->make(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class);
        $path = Path::with(['template', 'parts'])->findOrFail($request->getPathInfo());
        return $path;
    });
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Is this used often to stop this kind of thing happening? Pretty confused as to why this is being called and why the request path was "/".

Comment: @Zakalwe Yes, Laravel creates all service providers even for console run, so there. And request path is `/` because it is its default value. As different approach you can create a "deferred" service provider, so it won't be loaded every time, but only when it's needed ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/providers#deferred-providers))

Comment: Deferred seems a better idea as the object is only required at runtime. This gets rid of the need for the `runningInConsole()` call also so feels a bit tidier.